# Connection refused for spring cloud (Eureka/Ribbon) on pivotal web service

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I have a Spring Cloud application (Eureka, Ribbon, Zuul) that runs perfectly locally in Spring Tools Suite.  When I deploy to Pivotal Web Services, the services register with Eureka (i.e., they show up in the Eureka console), but when I try to have one service call another I get Connection refused.  When I try to go through Zuul, I get Forwarding Error followed by Connection refused.

I've tried various combinations of the following, but nothing seems to help.

```
eureka:
 client:
  serviceUrl:
   defaultZone: http://myeurekaserver.cfapps.io/eureka/
 instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
#   hostname: ${CF_INSTANCE_IP:localhost}
#   nonSecurePort: ${CF_INSTANCE_PORT:${PORT:${server.port:8002}}}
    hostname: ${vcap.application.uris[0]}
    nonSecurePort: 80
```

For the service to service calls I use the Autowired RestTemplate. In another part of my code I use the non-Autowired RestTemplate. When I use that with discoveryClient.getInstances(...) I do get back the ip address and ports of my services.  If I try to directly call those IP addresses/ports I also get Connection Refused.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the exact exception you are getting?

Comment: When I invoke through Zuul I get com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error.  Followed by - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 10.241.130.173:80 [/10.241.130.173] failed: Connection refused.  When I execute without Zuul (i.e., invoke a service directly that call another service) I just get the Connection refused.

Answer (score 2):

Found my own answer - In PWS, CF Networking has to be enabled.  Then one needs to apply rules to let services talk directly to each other.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/container-networking.html

Comment: After enabling the container-to-container networking using `cf add-network-policy` as you did, you just need to set the `preferIpAddress: true` property. The two others are required when you DON'T want to use the container-to-container network. Using them, you are telling the applications to register with Eureka using their external URLs so that the connectivity goes through the [Gorouters](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/architecture/router.html) PWS reverse proxies.

Answer (score 0):

Try these suggestions:

1. Restart the instance that runs Zuul and see if that solves the problem
2. Try monitoring the counter.servo.discoveryclient* values in /metrics

Comment: I've restarted Zuul and all the other components many times.  Here are the values in /metrics that I think you are referring to.  This is from the service that uses discoveryClient:

Comment: "counter.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_delete" :   5734  5821   5833  5841
"counter.servo.discoveryclient_reconcilehashcodemismatch" :  0
"counter.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_request" :   5874 5962 5974  5982
"counter.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_createnew" :   5736 5823 5835  5843
"counter.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_reuse" :    138 139 
"counter.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_release" :   5874  5962  5974  5982
"counter.servo.discoveryclient_reregister" :     0

Comment: Each counter value is for a subsequent run.  For example the first run at the top was 5734, second run 5821, third 5833, etc.

Comment: Just changed eureka.instance.preferIpAddress to false.  Now it finds the service, but is trying to invoke it by the instance ID - the value that shows up in the Eureka console.  It is doing the lookup on http://myServiceLogicalName/pathInThatService.  So, it is finding the right service, but can't invoke it by the instance ID.  I get: java.net.UnknownHostException: f6795e60-5d38-4903-4a0b-82859baa1c90

Comment: Just changed eureka.instance.preferIpAddress back to true.  It seems to find the correct internal IP of 10.241.80.169:8080 for my service.  Here is some more of the log:  Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for..myServiceName...Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused